# How to control the format of json file using Talend and the component tOutputJSON

Tags: arrays, json, object, talend

I would like to have an output JSON file using Talend, however, it seems that Talend gives us a certain JSON format. I would like to know how I can control and change the format of the JSON query, for example, to have an array instead of an object and vice-versa.

Thanks!

Comment: you won't have any dynamic methods in Talend to do your controls. I think the only way is to run your job and control the json file created when job is done.

Comment: Please clarify by adding some JSON examples  with the expected format.